# On load after Ajax Call in Event() of animaiton Not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, events

I have a scrip hat load all the data after ajax, on that response data`likeObj('#like'+postid).effect("bounce", {times:1,distance:25},400);`

this will give error that  likeObj is not a function.

What should I do for this, help me.

Thanks

```
 if(response=='OK')
                            {
                                    if(likeval==1)
                                    {
                                        var commentCount=likeobj("#firstPost"+postid+'1').text();
                                        //var newcount=+commentCount + +1;
                                        var  newcount=parseInt(commentCount) + parseInt(1);
                                        //likeobj('#like'+postid).effect("bounce", {times:1,distance:25},400);                                          
                                        likeobj("#firstPost"+postid+'1').html("<img alt='Image' src='images/like_icon.gif'> "+newcount);
                                        likeobj("#ullikesuser_"+user_id+"_"+postid).fadeIn(300, function() { likeobj("#ullikesuser_"+user_id+"_"+postid).append(likeobj("<li><?=getUserProfileImage($_SESSION['user_id'])?></li>").attr('id','lilikesuser_'+user_id+'_'+postid)); });
                                        //likeobj("#ullikesuser_"+user_id+"_"+postid).append(likeobj("<li><?=getUserProfileImage($_SESSION['user_id'])?></li>").attr('id','lilikesuser_'+user_id+'_'+postid));
                                        likeobj("#like"+postid).html(showhtml);
                                    }else{
                                        var commentCount=likeobj("#firstPost"+postid+'1').text();
                                        var  newcount=parseInt(commentCount) - parseInt(1); 
                                        //likeobj('#like'+postid).effect("bounce", {times:1,distance:25},400);
                                        likeobj("#firstPost"+postid+'1').html("<img alt='Image' src='images/like_icon.gif'> "+newcount);
                                        //$(this).fadeOut(500, function() { $(this).remove(); });
                                        likeobj("#lilikesuser_"+user_id+"_"+postid).fadeOut(200, function() { likeobj("#lilikesuser_"+user_id+"_"+postid).remove(); });
                                        likeobj("#like"+postid).html(showhtml);
                                        //likeobj("#like"+postid).html(response);
                                    }
                            }
```

.

After getting Response from ajax

Comment: Pls post some more code. Do you have a code line like $(document).ready()?

Comment: `likeObj` is obviously not a function, as you have'nt posted the code for `likeObj`, we have no idea why?

Comment: These codes are executing  after getting response of ajax,

Comment: likeObj is No Conflict Variable of the jquery

Comment: One More thing this code is working when document is loaded first...

Comment: Then I think you need to do delegate.

Comment: thanks every one, I have just put a line before call a function of NoConflict, it working fine..

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've not included jQuery ui file in your code.
Add jQuery UI and try.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```